# Find the rectangular region encompassing the extracted circle (point of interest) using the method extractSurFFeatures

Tags: matlab, detection, surf

Good morning, everyone, 
I hope you are doing well. Well, I have an image and I would like to extract or detect the points of interest using SURF detector. When I use the method provided by matlab I get the points of interest but for me I would like to get the patches, wish means the area of interest (rectangles), if there is a method you know I will be grateful. Thank you very much for your time and help. 
To better explain, i have an image [A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDxb6.jpg)
and i want to extract the regions (patches) using the function of matlab :

```
f=extractSurfFeatures(A);
```

unfortunately this function allows to extract the points of interest but for my case I want to extract the rectangles including these points as mentre the following figure  : 
[patches images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdqBg.png)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the C++ original SURF version I recently published. There you will find the size of the patches. https://github.com/herbertbay/SURF